# Why does comparing my two class return false?

Tags: c#

I dont understand. Why does comparing my class return false? I thought .Equals checks if each element are == to eachother and me should be each to me in both classes. So whats the problem and how do i get this to be true?

```
public class MyTest
{
    string me;
    public MyTest(){}
    public MyTest(string v) { me = v; }
    public static implicit operator string(MyTest v){return v.me;}
    public static implicit operator MyTest(string v) { return new MyTest(v); }
    public override string ToString(){ return me;}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", new MyTest("a").Equals( new MyTest("a")));
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", new MyTest("a") == new MyTest("a"));
        //false, false
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Classes are reference types.  So, the default 'Equals' method and equality operators, compare the 'references' of the instances (that is, the memory address) in order to verify if 2 instances are equal.

In other words: equality on reference types checks whether the 2 instances are the same instance.

You can override this behaviour, by overriding the Equals and GetHashCode methods.  Additionally, you can overload the equality and in-equality operators.

- [GetHashCode method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)
- [Equals
  method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)
- [== operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)
- [!= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You need to override the [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) method because by default, for reference types it compares their references:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as MyTest;
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return other.me == me;
}
```

Also when overriding the Equals method it is good practice to override the [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) method as well:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return (me ?? string.Empty).GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `Equals` method on the `MyTest` class and implement your custom comparison logic in that method. Without that the default implementation will compare only the references.

See this link - [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your class `MyTest` doesn't actually overload the operator `Equals`. So on the line where you call

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", new MyTest("a").Equals( new MyTest("a")));
```

that is, by default, just going to do the same thing as `==`.

You need to explicitly define equality in your class like this:

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    return (MyTest)obj.me == this.me;
}
```

that will actually compare the string inside this object to the one inside the other one. Now both calling `.Equals` and using the `==` operator will use your defined equality.

**Edit**: See @Darin Dimitrov's answer for a more comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing two classes but two different instance of class; the test returns false because you are comparing two different references.

You can override this behaviour, overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 1):

`struct` compares fields by default; `class` compares references by default. That doesn't mean you should simply make it a `struct`, as to avoid boxing etc you would also need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` **anyway** (plus `ToString`) - and by the time you've done that, you could have done it for the existing code.

For example:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyTest x, MyTest y) {
    if(x == null && y == null) return true;
    return x != null && y != null && x.me == y.me;
}
public static bool operator !=(MyTest x, MyTest y) {
    if (x == null && y == null) return false;
    return x == null || y == null || x.me != y.me;
}
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    MyTest other = obj as MyTest;
    return other != null && other.me == me;
}
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return me == null ? 0 : me.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Really? Structs will not be boxed unless you override GetHashCode, Equals and ToString? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @mgiuca: Good comment. @Marc Gravell: I always thought the reason for boxing is so the object has a vtable which can be used to identify what class (or struct) the object is. But logically that wouldnt be true if you can avoid boxing with structs. Once again my assumptions are wrong *sigh*. Why does GetHashCode and ToString help avoid boxing?

Comment: @mgiuca @acidzombie - this is a consequence of the `constrained` opcode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx) - if the struct doesn't implement it directly, it must box it to call the virtual object.* method

Comment: @mgiuca @acidzombie - in particular "If thisType is a value type and thisType implements method then ptr is passed unmodified as the 'this' pointer to a call  method instruction, for the implementation of method by thisType.

If thisType is a value type and thisType does not implement method then ptr is dereferenced, boxed, and passed as the 'this' pointer to the callvirt  method instruction."

Comment: @mgiuca @acidzombi - and I didn't say "they won't be boxed"; the point is that for `value.ToString()` (for example, with value-type `value`), it **must** box if the `struct` doesn't override `ToString()`; to **avoid** boxing as far as possible, therefore, override every possible virtual method.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: ah, i understand. Would all structs need to be boxed to pass it in as an object? I guess not. Since i see override in ValueType, enum and int i guess structs do have vtables. In that case why is there boxing at all? Lets take int for an example. It gets boxed and i see it implements the three function. Why does it need to be boxed, it looks like it covers the  3 points you mentioned from msdn.

Comment: nevermind from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28VS.80%29.aspx `This allows the value type to be stored on the garbage collected heap`. So i guess unboxed means stack while boxed means heap thus why it mentions the GC in that doc. Finally i tested a thought by writing `var o = (object)5; Test(o);` and `Test(object o) { o = 9; }`. o is still 5 after the call which is curious to me. Mostly how it decides if it should replace the value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Equals and '==' for reference types looks if two objects point to the same reference. It doesn´t check the values of the class. You have to override equals (or implement IEquatable) to provide your own logic to compare to instance of a class

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `object.Equals` (and `GetHashCode`). If you don't override the default implementation is to return whether they are the same object (and not compare fields).

Answer (score 0):

ehy not use a struct instead (which is a value type and is compared via the sum of the comparisons of its parts

```
public struct MyTest
{
    string me;
    public MyTest(string v) { me = v; }
    public static implicit operator string(MyTest v) { return v.me; }
    public static implicit operator MyTest(string v) { return new MyTest(v); }
    public override string ToString() { return me; }
}
```

Comment: While it is true that structs perform equality per-field by default, that *by itself* is not really a justification for making something a struct unnecessarily...

Comment: As the OP is performing implicit conversions with String, which is immutable, then a struct is likely to be a good canidate in this scenario

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, by default "==" identify if 2 object is the same; and "Equals" compare their values.